# how to compare two xml files having same data in different lines?

Tags: bash, shell, xml, file-comparison

I have two files have same data but in different lines.

File 1:

```
<Identities>
    <Identity>
        <Id>048206031415072010Comcast.USR8JR</Id>
        <UID>ccp_test_79</UID>
        <DisplayName>JOSH CCP</DisplayName>
        <FirstName>JOSH</FirstName>
        <LastName>CCP</LastName>
        <Role>P</Role>
        <LoginStatus>C</LoginStatus>
    </Identity>
    <Identity>
        <Id>089612381523032011Comcast.USR1JR</Id>
        <UID>94701_account1</UID>
        <DisplayName>account1</DisplayName>
        <FirstName>account1</FirstName>
        <LastName>94701</LastName>
        <Role>S</Role>
        <LoginStatus>C</LoginStatus>
    </Identity>
</Identities>
```

File 2 :

```
<Identities>
    <Identity>
        <Id>089612381523032011Comcast.USR1JR</Id>
        <UID>94701_account1</UID>
        <DisplayName>account1</DisplayName>
        <FirstName>account1</FirstName>
        <LastName>94701</LastName>
        <Role>S</Role>
        <LoginStatus>C</LoginStatus>
    </Identity>
    <Identity>
        <Id>048206031415072010Comcast.USR8JR</Id>
        <UID>ccp_test_79</UID>
        <DisplayName>JOSH CCP</DisplayName>
        <FirstName>JOSH</FirstName>
        <LastName>CCP</LastName>
        <Role>P</Role>
        <LoginStatus>C</LoginStatus>
    </Identity>
</Identities>
```

If I use `diff file1 file2` command I am getting below response:

```
1,10d0
<     <Identities>
<         <Identity>
<             <Id>048206031415072010Comcast.USR8JR</Id>
<             <UID>ccp_test_79</UID>
<             <DisplayName>JOSH CCP</DisplayName>
<             <FirstName>JOSH</FirstName>
<             <LastName>CCP</LastName>
<             <Role>P</Role>
<             <LoginStatus>C</LoginStatus>
<         </Identity>
20a11,20
>     <Identities>
>         <Identity>
>             <Id>048206031415072010Comcast.USR8JR</Id>
>             <UID>ccp_test_79</UID>
>             <DisplayName>JOSH CCP</DisplayName>
>             <FirstName>JOSH</FirstName>
>             <LastName>CCP</LastName>
>             <Role>P</Role>
>             <LoginStatus>C</LoginStatus>
>         </Identity>
```

But I need to get no difference, because these files having same data in different lines.

Comment: By sorting them linewise and comparing, you can check if they are *not equal*. Of course, equal after sorting does not mean that they are really equal as sorting destroys the XML syntax.

Comment: Don't know how to solve it.  they differ by order in file1 a then b and in file2 b then a. you may expose question with diff  -y -B -Z  -b --strip-trailing-cr  file1 file2

Comment: You could try `xmldiff`, but I think that will still notice the order changing, as order is relevant in generic XML. I think your best approach is to use an XML parser & generator to put each file in a canonical order and format, then use `xmldiff` or `diff`. A job for your favorite scripting language (Perl, Ruby, Python, etc.).

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve what you want with the help of a small Python script (you'll need Python installed, as well as the [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) toolkit).

**`tagsort.py`:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from lxml import etree

filename, tag = sys.argv[1:]

doc = etree.parse(filename, etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True))
root = doc.getroot()
root[:] = sorted(root, key=lambda el: el.findtext(tag))
print etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True)
```

This script sorts the first-level elements under the XML document root by the content of a second-level element, sending the result to stdout. It's called like this:

```
$ python tagsort.py filename tag
```

Once you've got that, you can use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to get a diff based on its output (I've added one element and changed another in your example files to show a non-empty result):

```
$ diff <(python tagsort.py file1 Id) <(python tagsort.py file2 Id)
4a5
>     <AddedTag>Something</AddedTag>
17c18
<     <Role>X</Role>
---
>     <Role>S</Role>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and I eventually found: https://superuser.com/questions/79920/how-can-i-diff-two-xml-files

That post suggests doing a canonical xml sort then doing a diff. The following should work for you if you are on linux, mac, or if you have windows something like cygwin installed:

```
$ xmllint --c14n File1.xml > 1.xml
$ xmllint --c14n File2.xml > 2.xml
$ diff 1.xml 2.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

It's tagged shell, but honestly I prefer using a scripting language with a parser. In this case `perl` with `XML::Twig`.

It goes something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

sub compare_by_identity {
   my ( $first, $second ) = @_;
   foreach my $identity ( $first->get_xpath('//Identity') ) {
      my $id = $identity->first_child_text('Id');

      print $id, "\n";
      my $compare_to =
        $second->get_xpath( "//Identity/Id[string()=\"$id\"]/..", 0 );
      if ($compare_to) {
         print "Matching element found for ID $id\n";
         foreach my $element ( $identity->children ) {
            my $tag  = $element->tag;
            my $text = $element->text;
            if ( not $element->text eq $compare_to->first_child_text($tag) ) {
               print "$id, $tag has value $text which doesn't match: ",
                 $compare_to->first_child_text($tag), "\n";
            }
         }
      }
      else {
         print "No matching element for Id $id\n";
      }
   }
}

my $first_file  = XML::Twig->new->parsefile('test1.xml');
my $second_file = XML::Twig->new->parsefile('test2.xml');

compare_by_identity( $first_file,  $second_file );
compare_by_identity( $second_file, $first_file );
```

I'm explicitly comparing one 'Identity' element at a time, and checking that all the fields in one, exist in the other, with the same value.

And then reversing that, because the second file *might* have extra entries.

Answer (score 0):

Using `xq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/:

```bsh
xq -sS '.[].Identities.Identity |= sort | .[0] == .[1]' file1.xml file2.xml
```

This reads in both XML files and translates them into JSON.  Each file appears as separate elements of the top-level array, so in the example above, `file1.xml`will be found in `.[0]` and `file2.xml` will be found in `.[1]` (this is done courtesy of the `-s` option).  The keys of each file will be automatically sorted due to the `-S` option.

The identities of each document are sorted and then the two documents are compared.

The output will be the string `true` for the data provided in the question, or `false` if a single change is made to either document.

You may use this in a shell test like so:

```bsh
if xq -e -sS '.[].Identities.Identity |= sort | .[0] == .[1]' file1.xml file2.xml >/dev/null
then
    echo 'documents are the same'
else
    echo 'documents are different'
fi
```

The `-e` option causes the exit status of `xq` to be zero if the last statement has a *true* boolean value.

---

For reference, the JSON document created internally for the two files in the question will look like this:

```json
[
  {
    "Identities": {
      "Identity": [
        {
          "DisplayName": "JOSH CCP",
          "FirstName": "JOSH",
          "Id": "48206031415072010Comcast.USR8JR",
          "LastName": "CCP",
          "LoginStatus": "C",
          "Role": "P",
          "UID": "ccp_test_79"
        },
        {
          "DisplayName": "account1",
          "FirstName": "account1",
          "Id": "089612381523032011Comcast.USR1JR",
          "LastName": "94701",
          "LoginStatus": "C",
          "Role": "S",
          "UID": "94701_account1"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "Identities": {
      "Identity": [
        {
          "DisplayName": "account1",
          "FirstName": "account1",
          "Id": "089612381523032011Comcast.USR1JR",
          "LastName": "94701",
          "LoginStatus": "C",
          "Role": "S",
          "UID": "94701_account1"
        },
        {
          "DisplayName": "JOSH CCP",
          "FirstName": "JOSH",
          "Id": "048206031415072010Comcast.USR8JR",
          "LastName": "CCP",
          "LoginStatus": "C",
          "Role": "P",
          "UID": "ccp_test_79"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```